# Correct Value not showing with knockout js databinding

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, knockout.js

I have a table with a pay button which will only show if the invoiced in greater than paid, but for some reason it only works when when the invoiced is equal to paid but if there is a payment which is partially paid that one the PAY button does not work.
Here is the code

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-right"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>
                    <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
                    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" data-bind="if: $data.invoiced_total() > $data.paid_total(), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
                        <span data-bind="ifnot: $data.invoiced_total() > $data.paid_total()"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGicA.png) which will show you what I mean, the partially paid should be able to PAY as well.

Comment: both conditions would show "pay" the only difference I see is that, one would be a link and the other a span element ... from what is shown in the screenshot is correct  ... ??

Comment: @Sam.C yea!, so the span wont allow the users to pay, but if the user has partially paid, they will get the link to PAY

Comment: Ah! can you include the binding for the "<td>" right before the last one in the post  ... that seems to work for you (the one that shows fully paid,open,partially paid)

Comment: why don't you just conditionally style/enable the link to make it appear enabled/disabled instead of switching between two on/off controls?

Comment: @Sam.C can you show me what you mean? I did not understand

Comment: @dperry how do I do that? but this is the way knockout js works and should work, so why the issue?

Comment: you could use the `css` binding to apply a style to make the link appear enabled/disabled, and move the `if` check into the click function. possibly move the `if` check code into a helper function such as `canPay` to pull your logic out of the view

Comment: The HTML code you posted in the question is the "<td>" element that is used by KO to render the last column of the table in the screenshot right? .. Can you also include the HTML "<td>" element definition that is used to render the second column from the last column? ... or if you don't mind include the full table HTML ...

Comment: @Sam.C I showed the whole table now

Comment: @dperry you were talking about some buttons?

Comment: @Sam.C can you see it ?

Comment: @MasnadNehith Yes ... my theory here is the values you are comparing the if/ifnot binding are compared as string type ... so for example "1000" is less than "2" when compared as string .. I have added my recommendation as an answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely the two variables you are comparing are string values

"212.10">"60.60" is false but 212.10> 60.60 is true ... so this might solve your issue (converting to float before comparing)

```
<td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
                        <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a button instead, as the intent is clearer, as is enabling/disabling/styling it:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-right"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span></td>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>
                    <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
                    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button data-bind="enable: $data.invoiced_total() > $data.paid_total(), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice">pay</button>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: yea but now the button is shown in all the places, I want people to know that they cannot click the button or the pay link when its fully paid, and also why is there 2 buttons

Comment: @MasnadNehith that's where the `enable` binding comes in. the button is disabled using the same if/ifnot check you were using before.

Comment: I'd say an enabled/disabled button is better UI than a link/text and lets the user know what their options are, as well

Comment: But the button is not shown in a way where users cannot click, the bottons everywhere looks like it can be clicked, hence I used links

Comment: a disabled button looks noticeably different than a clickable one. you can also style it further with css

Comment: So I tried the buttons but even so now the partially paid cannot be selected!